# HTC Device: native keyboard is displayed when edit text is setEnabled(false)

Tags: android, android-layout

In HTC device even when we set the editText.setEnabled(false) the native keyboard pop's up.
When we do a double tap it shows the cut copy paste options , which we don't want.

For that we applied the fix of editText.setRawInputType(EditorInfo.TYPE_NULL);  , but after applying this the keyboard showing issue is fixed but the cut copy paste options still come up.

Help Appreciated.

Thanks!
Bhushan

Comment: isn't it possible to replace "EditText" with "TextView"?

Answer (score 0):

In [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1109022/close-hide-the-android-soft-keyboard) question there is a method how to hide soft keyboard. It worked for me.

They say:

```
InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager)getSystemService(
      Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(myEditText.getWindowToken(), 0);
```

Answer (score 0):

when you enable pls use this it will not diplay keyboard
getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_ALWAYS_HIDDEN);

**OR**
this.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
this.getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_ALWAYS_HIDDEN);
 setContentView(R.layout.mainlist);

Comment: Even after applying this the cut copy paste option comes on the screen , we don't want this feature to be enabled . This issue is coming only on the HTC devices.